# excel formula to display right column

Tags: excel-2007

I need an excel formula for this to produce the values on the right column. simple theory. to show when right values has jump by a certain value.

```
10 0
10 1
11 0
11 1
12 0
12 0
12 0
12 1
13 0
13 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want 1 when the next value is different, and zero otherwise?

If so, assuming your values are in column A, starting with A1, try the following formula in B1: `=IF(A1=A2;0;1)` then copy B1 and paste in the whole column B.

Make that `=IF(ISBLANK(A2);0;IF(A1=A2;0;1))` to also return 0 if the next cell is blank.